# Open GNU Scientific Library Documentation within emacs?

Tags: help, documentation

How do I open documentation of the [GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/index.html) within emacs?

Comment: Which platform are you on? Which format is the documentation in? Debian/Ubuntu provide a package called `gsl-doc-info` which packages the documentation in Info format, which is very well suited to Emacs. After installing you can then `C-h i m gsl-ref RET` and browse it.

Comment: For info files you just need to add the gsl doc directory to `Info-directory-list`. That should be available: ["sphinx is able to produce info output, so we will be providing info files with GSL"](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gsl/2017-04/msg00009.html). You can view the html doc via [`eww`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eww.html).

Comment: @Basil unfortunately I am running OSX. @Tobias I think I will try to get the info files from Sphinx. And thanks did not know about the `Info-directory-list`

Comment: Did you figure out the answer to your question?